# How do Facebook calls a function without the script being loaded first?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've been analyzing Facebook JS SDK debug source code, and, doing some tests with the quickstart Facebook JS SDK code, I've found that the FB.init function is declared in fbAsyncInit function, even if the async loading script is not still loaded(?).

I've interpreted this from the following code:

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '{your-app-id}',
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });
  }


  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));
```

Anyone is able to explain what is going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know `async loading script is not still loaded`? Of course it is loaded and that is why `FB.init` is initialized

Comment: Yeah, I understand it does load. But how does it pass by the object FB and function init() without throwing an error of FB not declared?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't quite clear, but I'll try to explain the flow-

The code-

```
function(d){
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
```

loads the facebook's js sdk asynchronously. Now the following code-

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '{your-app-id}',
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });
}
```

has nothing to do where it is included in the file, since it `window.fbAsyncInit` will only be triggered automatically after the SDK is loaded. When this is triggered, the `FB` is initialized successfully! That's it. Hope that helps!

Comment: However trying to build a similar library, as soon as code is being parsed, it throws an exception as the object is not declared (and I am not calling any window.asyncInit function anywhere), just declaring it, just like Facebook does.

Comment: Sorry but am not sure what you really trying to do!

Comment: At first, trying to understand why does the parser would not complain about FB haven't been declared, as script is only loading after the fbAsyncInit script.